# AntiForgery Asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this for Anti Forgery in my asp.net 4.5 web form application.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="formCont" method="post">
     <%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>
```

using Namespace

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
```

and on page load

```
 AntiForgery.Validate();
```

it's working fine. 
Now I have created may `asp generic handler` for ajax call from javascript. Now the issue is how can I validate the same in my generic handler.

I have tried this in my ajax call

```
 data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val() },
```

and in handler trying this `AntiForgery.Validate();` but I am getting the exception

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException' occurred in System.Web.WebPages.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

I have checked in and I am getting the values in `context.Request["__RequestVerificationToken"]`

how can I over come this issue.

Comment: What format are you posting the data with? JSON? `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @mason it's default I don't specified any.

Comment: Then look at the AJAX request using your browser's network tools. Compare that to what a normal post looks like. Spot the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

It was looking in `context.Request.Forms` collection so I make a small change as below

1. Change the request type to post `type: "POST",`

and bingo it worked.